# How to print no of copies from printer

Tags: c#-4.0, printing

i am creating a windows program. There i want to print a pdf on number of time that is defined by the user. I did the code that is below . 
Problem in my code  print only one copy every time but i want as user set how many copy he want to print .

```
 int NumOfLabel =  10; /* here for example i set to 10 copy */
 Process objProcess1 = new Process();
 FileName = @"D:\Project\Document\2320.pdf";
 //Print the file 
 PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
 pdi.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)NumOfLabel;
 if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
  PrinterName = pdi.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
 /// Set the printer.
 AddPrinterConnection(PrinterName);
 SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterName);
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.Verb = "Print";
 info.FileName = FileName;
 info.CreateNoWindow = true;
 info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
 info.UseShellExecute = true;
 objProcess1.StartInfo = info;
 objProcess1.Start();
 MessageBox.Show("Print done.");
 }   

 //Add the printer connection for specified pName.
 [DllImport("winspool.drv")]
  private static extern bool AddPrinterConnection(string pName);
 //Set the added printer as default printer.
 [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
```

Can you please tell me what i am doing mistake or what i need to do. Thanks for you comment and answer.

Comment: "Not all printers support printing multiple copes. You can use the MaximumCopies property to determine the maximum number of copies the printer supports. If the number of copies is set higher than the maximum copies supported by the printer, only the maximum number of copies will be printed, and no exception will occur." - [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.copies(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Pay attention that you are trying to print from page 1 to 10. Did your PDF file contains 10 pages? You might wanted to print 10 times instead

Comment: Check that the printer supports multiple copies. If it doesn't you'll have to loop

Comment: @ehh i want to print 10 copy of my document

Comment: @ehh - If that were an issue it wouldn't print at all rather than only printing one copy.

Comment: I know, it was just a comment in addition to his issue. Anyway, you are still printing 10 pages

Comment: @A.Goutam We get that, but setting the ToPage to the number of copies is not the way do that. At first glance your code looks OK, but see my comment about the printer actually supporting multiple copies.

Comment: @ehh basic problem with the code is want to print number of copy for a single document. I can remove that code `pdi.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;pdi.PrinterSettings.ToPage = NumOfLabel;` no problem

Comment: So we are open the same page. Again it was only a comment not the solution of the problem. Multiple copies support looks as the answer of your problem

Comment: I now notice that you're not actually passing the printer settings to the printer.

Comment: @chrisF so how this is printing 1 copy properly

Comment: @A.Goutam because you are setting `info.FileName = FileName;` and so telling the process which file to print.

Comment: Which printer are you using?

Comment: @ehh I am using HP Laser Jet 1020 Printer

Comment: @ChrisF so what i  need to do with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Acrobat documentation, you will not be able to set the number of copies.

[image]

You need to loop in order to print multiple number of copies

You can try the following code:

```
    public static void Print(string pdfFileName, string printerName, int copies)
    {
        if (File.Exists(pdfFileName))
        {
            const string flagNoSplashScreen = "/s";
            const string flagOpenMinimized = "/h";

            var acrobatReaderApplicationPath = GetAcrobatReaderApplicationPath();
            if (acrobatReaderApplicationPath == null)
            {
                throw new AcrobatNotInstalledException();
            }

            var flagPrintFileToPrinter = string.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", pdfFileName, printerName);
            var args = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", flagNoSplashScreen, flagOpenMinimized, flagPrintFileToPrinter);

            for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = acrobatReaderApplicationPath,
                        Arguments = args,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        Verb = "Print",
                        ErrorDialog = false,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    };
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();

                    if (process != null)
                    {
                        process.WaitForInputIdle();
                        process.CloseMainWindow();
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

private static string GetAcrobatReaderApplicationPath()
    {
        string applicationPath;

        var printApplicationRegistryPaths = new[]
        {
            @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRD32.exe",
            @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe"
        };

        foreach (var printApplicationRegistryPath in printApplicationRegistryPaths)
        {
            using (var regKeyAppRoot = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(printApplicationRegistryPath))
            {
                if (regKeyAppRoot == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                applicationPath = (string)regKeyAppRoot.GetValue(null);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPath))
                {
                    return applicationPath;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this code, but machine have not acrobat reader then this code will not work

Comment: So how does it print it behind the scene? I was sure it using Acrobat reader.

Comment: maybe system have cutePDF then and there are many many more like this

Comment: cutePDF, PrimoPDF, pdffactory... all are virtual printers to print to PDF. But you are trying to print a PDF file to a physical printer, aren't you?

Comment: right but in my case there are not acrobat reader on client system

Comment: Weird to me but anyway, not sure but try to use my code and instead of searching for reader in registry, search for CutePDF. Maybe it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117818/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-ehh).